# Are there any standard icons for qml-app-development?

Tags: application-development, ubuntu-touch

I am developing a qml-app and I want to put icons on the buttons. I would like to use ubuntu standard icons to get the real ubuntu look for my app. How can I do this?

Comment: You want to use icons from someone else? Mind the copyright! An icon is a creative work. It's copyrighted. So you should first check the copyright-license that comes with that icon. I had [this webpage](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2012/10/canonical-hire-faenza-designer-to-work-on-new-ubuntu-icon-set) in my bookmarks. It's about Canonical - the business behind Ubuntu - hiring the 'Faenza' guy to create new icons.

Comment: http://www.iloveubuntu.net/ubuntu-mobile-icon-theme-updated-new-icons-reaches-200-icons-stage

Comment: Surely, the api must provide a way to get an icon from the system wide theme. Why was this closed?

Answer (score 8):

The official Ubuntu Touch icon theme is called Ubuntu Mobile, and is available for installation in the `ubuntu-mobile-icons` package. Here is a sample of the icons provided:

[image: Ubuntu Mobile Action icons]

To use the icons in your code, just use the path to the icon. For example, to set the icon in a toolbar button, do something similar to this:

```
ToolbarButton {
    text: i18n.tr("Refresh")
    iconSource: Qt.resolvedUrl("/usr/share/icons/ubuntu-mobile/actions/scalable/reload.svg")
}
```

To avoid having to repeat the root path over and over again, I usually use a small function called `getIcon` which returns the actual path to an icon:

```
function getIcon(name) {
    return Qt.resolvedUrl("/usr/share/icons/ubuntu-mobile/actions/scalable/" + name + ".svg")
}
```

The previous example would then be:

```
ToolbarButton {
    text: i18n.tr("Refresh")
    iconSource: getIcon("reload")
}
```

Comment: This answer needs to be updated. The correct and official way of using icons is,
iconName: "reload" or
iconSource: "image://theme/reload"

Answer (score 4):

I've only just started dabbling in QML, but it looks like the Ubuntu SDK provides a way to access icons from the theme, the [Icon component.](http://developer.ubuntu.com/api/qml/sdk-1.0/Ubuntu.Components.Icon/) Here's a Hello Worldish example:

```cpp
import QtQuick 2.0
import Ubuntu.Components 0.1

MainView {
    id: root
    objectName: "mainView"

    width: units.gu(50)
    height: units.gu(75)

    property real margins: units.gu(2)
    property real buttonWidth: units.gu(9)

    Page {
        title: i18n.tr("Icons!")

    Column {

        anchors {
            fill: parent
            margins: root.margins
        }
        spacing: units.gu(1)

        Icon {
            name: "call-start"
            width: 48
            height: 48
         }

        Icon {
            name: "call-stop"
            width: 48
            height: 48
         }

        Icon {
            name: "find"
            width: 48
            height: 48
        }

        }
    }
}
```

This gives you:

[image: qml-icons-hello-world]

AFAICT, this doesn't actually seem to support the full set of icons provided by the Freedesktop Icon Theme Specification though.....

Answer (score 0):

The default theme for Ubuntu mobile is Suru and the icons are located in `/usr/share/icons/suru`

Any of the icons can be used by name. Even icons outside the Suru icon set.

If the file is `/usr/share/icons/suru/actions/scalable/like.svg`

The code could be:

```
Action {
    id: likeAction
    iconName: "like"    // the files name without file ending
    text: "I like this"
}
```

Which gives you an action button with a heart icon.